# Java CEF IntelliJ plugin support UnsatisfiedLinkError on init (Linux)

Tags: java, c++, linux, chromium-embedded, intellij-plugin

I am working on Java Chromium Embedded Framework https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef/src/master/. I aim to embed the browser into IntelliJ IDEA plugins for Windows and Linux.

I build native library parts from source code. Project example apps work both Win and Linux, but when I embed it into IntelliJ IDEA it crashes on Ubuntu at initialization method (works on windows though). Previously I had some issues on Windows and was able to debug C++ code with Visual Studio. Now I am not sure how to debug on Ubuntu.

On Linux I use cmake and make to build the library:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug..
make -j4
```

Init crash error stack trace:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.cef.CefApp.N_PreInitialize()Z
    at org.cef.CefApp.N_PreInitialize(Native Method)
    at org.cef.CefApp.access$000(CefApp.java:24)
    at org.cef.CefApp$1.run(CefApp.java:162)
    at org.cef.CefApp.<init>(CefApp.java:167)
    at org.cef.CefApp.getInstance(CefApp.java:220)
    at org.cef.CefApp.getInstance(CefApp.java:207)
...
```

On JCEF forum there is thread with similar issues on Linux (https://github.com/CodeBrig/Journey/issues/3), but no good tips on debugging. Any suggestions would be appreciated.